# PMF of geometric compensated scaled Poisson

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $S_t=S_0e^{X_t}$ where $X_t=aN_t-bt$ for positive constants $a,b>0$ and $N_t$ is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ per unit time, so $N_t$ has mean $\lambda t$.

**Question**
What is the PMF $S_t$ (or $X_t$)?

We know that $$\{S_t \leq s\}=\left\{N_t \leq \frac{\log(s/S_0)+bt}a\right\}.$$ The CDF of $N$ is only defined on non-negative integers, so I am unsure if we can simply take the corresponding CDF of $N$ as a real function of $s$ and differentiate it to find the PMF. Is this possible? If not, how else can we find the PMF? We could certainly also invert the CF, as $X_t$ has a CF $e^{-btu}\phi_N(au)$ where $\phi_N(u)$ is the CF of a $Pois(\lambda t)$ RV. But I can’t see a closed form inversion at the moment, and while a numerical scheme is okay, I am curious if there is anything more explicit. Thanks.

Comment: $N_t$ is discrete, so $S_t$ is discrete, so $S_t$ does not have a pdf. It has a pmf.

Comment: @MikeEarnest If $X_t$ had no drift then it would only take discrete values that are positive multiples of $a$, yes, but it has a continuous drift downward. Does this not affect its range?

Comment: For each fixed $t$, the random variable $X_t$ is discrete.

Comment: @MikeEarnest yes I see. I have updated the terminology then.

Comment: $$
P(S_t=s)=P\left(N_t=\frac{\log (s/S_0)+bt}{a}\right)
$$
and you have a formula for the latter. Is that what you are looking for? The quantity on the left is the pmf of $S_t$, but surely this is something you could have figured out on your own. I think you might not be articulating the actual question you have.

Comment: To be crystal clear, $P(N_t=k)=e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}$, so combine that with the last comment.

Comment: @MikeEarnest indeed thank you, just a slight lapse in reason where I mistook the RV for a continuous RV, which feels silly now. I only wanted to verify the form of the PMF before I began looking into MLE for the parameters. Thank you.